# Set boolean value inside one if statement so another if statement can check if it is true

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Basically, this code detects at which side of the screen the mouse is, and rotates the camera to look at it when the right mouse button is pressed, basically it aims at the direction the player is looking.

Issue I ran into is that it also rotates back based on the position of the mouse, if the player is looking to the right and press the aim button, the camera would rotate 20 degrees, and than rotate back -20 degrees when the button goes up, and it works fine until you aim to the right, and after pressing the aim button, look left, this will rotate 20 degrees, than the camera will rotate another 20 degrees, making for a total of 40 instead of the 0 it should be

So how I decided to overcome this was by setting a bool that basically tells at which side you are aiming, and will move based on that value, issue is I have no idea how to set the bool from inside the if statement so other if statements can read it.

I tried doing it the way you see below but basically it just doesn't work. I also tried to put the second if statement inside the first one, but it completely ignores it

This is what I am doing

```
bool isCameraRight = true;
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1) && mouse.x < Screen.width / 2)
        {
            //Code
            isCameraRight = false;
        }
        if (!isCameraRight && Input.GetMouseButtonUp(1))
        {
            //Code
        }
```

This is something I also tried and didn't work, it just ignores the second if statement always

```
if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1) && mouse.x < Screen.width / 2)
        {
            //Code
            if (!isCameraRight && Input.GetMouseButtonUp(1))
            {
            //Code
            }
        }
```

And this is how the final code in my Unity script looks like

```
private void Update()
    {
        var mouse = new Vector2(Input.mousePosition.x, Screen.height - Input.mousePosition.y);
        bool isCameraRight = true;

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1) && mouse.x > Screen.width / 2)
        {
            this.transform.Rotate(0, Mathf.Lerp(0, 25, 15), 0);
            cinemachineVirtualCamera.m_Lens.FieldOfView = Mathf.Lerp(40, 35, 37);
            isCameraRight = true;
        }
        if (isCameraRight && Input.GetMouseButtonUp(1))
        {
            this.transform.Rotate(0, Mathf.Lerp(0, -25, 15), 0);
            cinemachineVirtualCamera.m_Lens.FieldOfView = Mathf.Lerp(35, 40, 37);
        }

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1) && mouse.x < Screen.width / 2)
        {
            this.transform.Rotate(0, Mathf.Lerp(0, -25, 15), 0);
            cinemachineVirtualCamera.m_Lens.FieldOfView = Mathf.Lerp(40, 35, 37); ;
            isCameraRight = false;

        }
        if (!isCameraRight && Input.GetMouseButtonUp(1))
        {
            this.transform.Rotate(0, Mathf.Lerp(0, 25, 15), 0);
            cinemachineVirtualCamera.m_Lens.FieldOfView = Mathf.Lerp(35, 40, 37);
        }   
    }
```

What is the best way to go about doing this?

Please don't delete this, I am stupid, not a coder, just trying my best and really need this to work

Comment: Is the problem that when you release the mouse button, you need to know whether it was right or left when it was clicked? If that's true you need an instance variable (outside this method) which stores that info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not into Unity, but I think you first need to simply set `isCameraRight` from the start and then just use that variable, no need to check the same thing many times.

```
private void Update()
{
    var mouse = new Vector2(Input.mousePosition.x, Screen.height - Input.mousePosition.y);
    bool isCameraRight = mouse.x > Screen.width / 2;

    if (isCameraRight)
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1))
        {
            this.transform.Rotate(0, Mathf.Lerp(0, 25, 15), 0);
            cinemachineVirtualCamera.m_Lens.FieldOfView = Mathf.Lerp(40, 35, 37);
        }
        else if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(1))
        {
            this.transform.Rotate(0, Mathf.Lerp(0, -25, 15), 0);
            cinemachineVirtualCamera.m_Lens.FieldOfView = Mathf.Lerp(35, 40, 37);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1))
        {
            this.transform.Rotate(0, Mathf.Lerp(0, -25, 15), 0);
            cinemachineVirtualCamera.m_Lens.FieldOfView = Mathf.Lerp(40, 35, 37); ;
        }
        else if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(1))
        {
            this.transform.Rotate(0, Mathf.Lerp(0, 25, 15), 0);
            cinemachineVirtualCamera.m_Lens.FieldOfView = Mathf.Lerp(35, 40, 37);
        }
    }
}
```

If you need to store the value of `isCameraRight` from a *previous* click, you need to use an instance variable.

Comment: instance variable was the thing that fixed it, thanks!